# Convert video file to byte array and save within app

Tags: arrays, react-native, video-processing, data-conversion, file-conversion

I am trying save some video in react native app privately. So that i can download videos within app and can watch within app after download. So i am not able to get it how can i do this. Let me know if anybody have resolution for this approach. i was checking that we can convert files into byte than can store within react native app. again then convert into video and can watch it within app. Let me know if this can be done by anyone. Thanks

```
<Video source={{uri: "background"}}
       ref={(ref) => {
         this.player = ref
       }}                             
       onBuffer={this.onBuffer}
       onError={this.videoError}
       style={styles.backgroundVideo} />
```

[Watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfObQmSWjkk)

You can watch the above video. Anybody have a idea that how mx doing this thing. I want to do same. Download videos and save and will be private and play in my app.

Answer (score 1):

For downloading any file like video,img ..

there are two best known libraries for downloading files

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch-blob

Now you can follow their documentation to download files like Videos,images or whatever you want to your user's phone.

For the part that you dont want it to be available to user via gallery.

For this you can use react-native-fetchblob as it has builtin intent actions and views. You can download a video file with any random name like 1234CACHE any random name without any extension to it, specially dont give it extension like video.mp4 because gallery detects .mp4 files so dont give it any extension and the file won't be available in any gallery.

Now how to hide the file? react-native-fetch-blob allow us to save files into directories that are not publicly available i mean user cannot reach those directory and these directories are used only for saving App's data so you can save your video file in one of these directories.

Now after completing your download, You can open your file with the Intent.

***Example:***

```
const VIDEO_PATH = res.path() //the path where your downloaded video is saved, you will actually receive this in the response of download function.

const MIME_TYPE = "video/mp4"

//Now finally call the intent with video mime so the video will be opened in user's media player, or if you want  your own media player you can use any library for that.

 android.actionViewIntent(VIDEO_PATH , MIME_TYPE)
```

Comment: for the video u sent, they could be only using an API that return the images of movies not downloading them (which i suggest you to use)

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://github.com/RonRadtke/react-native-blob-util to download any remote files

Comment: Hi @KingAmo is this library decrypt my videos before download